# What style to use when naming types in C

Tags: c, naming-conventions

According to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797), the "_t" postfix on type names is reserved in C. When using `typedef` to create a new opaque type, I'm used to having some sort of indication in the name that this is a type. Normally I would go with something like `hashmap_t` but now I need something else.

Is there any standard naming scheme for types in C? In other languages, using CapsCase like `Hashmap` is common, but a lot of C code I see doesn't use upper case at all. CapsCase works fairly nicely with a library prefix too, like `XYHashmap`.

So is there a common rule or standard for naming types in C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, POSIX reserves names ending `_t` if you include any of the POSIX headers, so you are advised to stay clear of those - in theory.  I work on a project that has run afoul of such names two or three times over the last twenty or so years.  You can minimize the risk of collision by using a corporate prefix (your company's TLA and an underscore, for example), or by using mixed case names (as well as the `_t` suffix); all the collisions I've seen have been short and all-lower case (`dec_t`, `loc_t`, ...).

Other than the system-provided (and system-reserved) `_t` suffix, there is no specific widely used convention.  One of the mixed-case systems (camelCase or InitialCaps) works well.  A systematic prefix works well too - the better libraries tend to be careful about these.

If you do decide to use lower-case and `_t` suffix, do make sure that you use long enough names and check diligently against the POSIX standard, the primary platforms you work on, and any you think you might work on to avoid unnecessary conflicts.  The worst problems come when you release some name `example_t` to customers and then find there is a conflict on some new platform.  Then you have to think about making customers change their code, which they are always reluctant to do.  It is better to avoid the problem up front.

Answer (score 5):

The [Indian Hill style guidelines](http://www.psgd.org/paul/docs/cstyle/cstyle11.htm) have some suggestions:

> Individual projects will no doubt have
>   their own naming conventions. There
>   are some general rules however.
>
> - Names with leading and trailing underscores are reserved for system
>     purposes and should not be used for
>     any user-created names. Most systems
>     use them for names that the user
>     should not have to know. If you must
>     have your own private identifiers,
>     begin them with a letter or two
>     identifying the package to which they
>     belong.
> - `#define` constants should be in all CAPS.
> - Enum constants are Capitalized or in all CAPS
> - Function, typedef, and variable names, as well as struct, union, and
>     enum tag names should be in lower
>     case.
> - Many macro "functions" are in all CAPS. Some macros (such as getchar and
>     putchar) are in lower case since they
>     may also exist as functions.
>     Lower-case macro names are only
>     acceptable if the macros behave like a
>     function call, that is, they evaluate
>     their parameters exactly once and do
>     not assign values to named parameters.
>     Sometimes it is impossible to write a
>     macro that behaves like a function
>     even though the arguments are
>     evaluated exactly once.
> - Avoid names that differ only in case, like foo and Foo. Similarly,
>     avoid foobar and foo_bar. The
>     potential for confusion is
>     considerable.
> - Similarly, avoid names that look like each other. On many terminals and
>     printers, 'l', '1' and 'I' look quite
>     similar. A variable named 'l' is
>     particularly bad because it looks so
>     much like the constant '1'.
>
> In general, global names (including
>   enums) should have a common prefix
>   identifying the module that they
>   belong with. Globals may alternatively
>   be grouped in a global structure.
>   Typedeffed names often have "_t"
>   appended to their name.
>
> Avoid names that might conflict with
>   various standard library names. Some
>   systems will include more library code
>   than you want. Also, your program may
>   be extended someday.

Comment: Doesn't this suggest to use the exact same convention the OP has an issue with?  Seems to be answering a different question than asked, which is focused on types.

Answer (score 3):

C only reserves *some* uses of a `_t` suffix.  As far as I can tell, this is only current identifiers ending with `_t` plus any identifier that starts `int` or `uint` (7.26.8).  However, POSIX may reserve more.

It's a general problem in C, since you have extremely flat namespaces, and there's no silver bullet.  **If you're familiar with CapCase names and they work well for you, then you should continue to use them.**  Otherwise, you'll have to evaluate the goals of the current project and see which solution best meets them.

Comment: +1 for CapCase. Makes things nice if you later migrate to a language with classes too, and it's familiar for type names.

Answer (score 2):

CapsCase is often used for types in C.

For instance, if you look at projects in the GNOME ecosystem (GTK+, GDK, GLib, GObject, Clutter, etc.), you'll see types like `GtkButton` or `ClutterStageWindow`. They **only** use CapsCase for data types; function names and variables are all lower-case with underscore separators - e.g. `clutter_actor_get_geometry()`.

Type naming schemes are like indentation conventions - they generate religious wars with people asserting some sort of moral superiority for their preferred approach. It is certainly preferable to follow the style in existing code, or in related projects (e.g. for me, GNOME over the last few years.)

However, if you're starting from scratch and have no template, there's no hard-and-fast rule. If you're interested in coding efficiently and leaving work at reasonable hour so you can go home and have a beer or whatever, you certainly should pick a style and stick to it for your project, but it matters very little exactly which style you pick.

Answer (score 2):

One alternate solution that works reasonably well is to use uppercase for all type names and macro names.  Global variables may be CapCase (CamelBack) and all local variables lower case.

This technique helps to improve readability and also takes advantage of language syntax which reduces the number of pollution characters in variable names; e.g. gvar, kvar, type_t, etc.  For example, data types cannot be syntatically confused with any other type.

Global variables are easily distinguished from locals by having at least one upper case letter.

I agree that prefixed or postfixed underscores should be avoided in all token names.

Lets look at the example below.

Its readily clear that InvertedCount is a global due to its case.  It's equally clear that INT32U and RET_ERR are types due to their sytax.  Its also clear that INVERT_VAL() is a macro due to the fact thats its on the right hand side and there is no cast so it cant be a data type.

One thing is for sure though.  Whichever method you use, it should be inline with your organizations coding standard.  For me, the least amount of clutter, the better.

Of course, style is a different issue.

```
#define  INVERT_VAL(x)   (~x)
#define  CALIBRATED_VAL  100u

INT32U  InvertedCount;

typedef  enum {
    ERR_NONE = 0,
    ...
} RET_ERR;

RET_ERR  my_func (void) 
{
    INT32U  val;
    INT32U  check_sum;


    val           = CALIBRATED_VAL;   // --> Lower case local variable.
    check_sum     = INVERT_VAL(val);  // --> Clear use of macris.

    InvertedCount = checksum;         // --> Upper case global variable.  
                                      //     Looks different no g prefix required.

    ... 

    return (ERR_NONE); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ideas and opinion on this subject, but there is no one universal standard for naming types.  The most important thing is to be consistent. In the absence of coding standards, when maintaining code, resist the urge to use another naming convention.  Introducing a new naming convention, even if it's perfect, can add unnecessary complexity.

This is actually a great topic to raise when interviewing people. I've never come across a good programmer that didn't have an opinion on this.  No opinion or no passion in the answer indicates that the person isn't an experienced programmer.